# How do I make my links appear as images, and have them change with hover and so on?

Tags: css

How do I make my links appear as images, and have them change with hover and so on? I already have the button images. Basically the website I'm making is pretty basic, but it's nice. The one issue I'm having is with my nav bar. The navigation bar has four links, and I want them to appear as images, and change with hover. The links are in an unordered list - it looks like this:

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="Home Page.html">Home page</a>
  <li><a href="Information.html">Information</a>
  <li><a href="Forum.html">Forum</a>
  <li><a href="Interests.html">Interests</a>
</ul>
```

I have the CSS, and I'm looking to attribute images to each link. I know how to add colors but not images.

Comment: Add `background-image` property to your CSS for the links

Comment: .navbar:hover {
 background:url(pictures/buttons/interests1.) repeat-x;

Comment: How do I change the buttons for each link individually and not the whole navbar. So I can have seperate images for each link, not the whole unordered list, if that makes sense.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you want your links to be accessible and localizable - using images allows neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about placing images in your captions as such:

```
<a href="#">
<img src="images/yourImage.png" alt="Your Image">
</a>
```

You can then use jquery to change the source of the image once its hovered on.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

See at http://jsbin.com/acuhuy/5/edit

```
  <div id="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="Home Page.html">Home Page</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="Information.html">Information</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="Forum.html">Forum</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="Interests.html">Interests</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#nav{
  position:relative;
}
ul#menu{

}
li.menu-item{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:80px;
  height:27px;
  padding-top:2px;
  margin-right:5px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image:url('http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/glossy_buttons/glossy_button_blank_black_rectangle.png');
  background-size:80px 27px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;

}
li.menu-item a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f0f0f0;
}

li.menu-item:hover{
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `li.menu-item:hover{background-image:url('some other image')}`